# Find missing gaps in table records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a list of table record of this kind:

```
20180108001
20180108002
20180108003
20180108004
```

and so on

At a certain point this sequence broke up like this

```
20180108099
20180108102
```

missing 100 and 101 record

Is there a "select" command to extract the first NON sequential record?

Comment: What have you tried so far? :-)

Comment: Writing a query starts with an algorithm. So: what makes the  20180108102 record different from the ones before?

Comment: Do you want 100, 101 or 102 as result?

Answer (score 4):

To return 20180108100, select the previous row and add 1.

```
select min(col + 1)
from tablename
where col + 1 not in (select col from tablename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way to list all the "holes" for a certain date :

```
SELECT x AS gap_from, next_x AS gap_to
  FROM ( SELECT x, LEAD(x) OVER (ORDER BY x) next_x
            FROM ( SELECT SUBSTR(the_column,-4,3) AS x 
                         FROM the_table 
                         WHERE the_column LIKE '201808%'
                        )
  )
  WHERE x <> next_x-1
```

It will return :

```
gap_from | gap_to
-----------------
099      | 102
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()` function, like here:

```
with t (a) as (
  select 20180107099 from dual union all
  select 20180108002 from dual union all
  select 20180108003 from dual union all
  select 20180108004 from dual )
select a from (select a, lag(a) over(order by a) + 1 as lg from t)
  where lg <> a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` :

```
select t.* 
from (select t.*, id - (row_number() over (order by id)) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use sub-query and  self join

```
select min(t.id) from t
where t.id  in (

   select t1.id from t t1
          left  join t t2 on t1.id=t2.id+1
          where t2.id is null
               )
```

Comment: That's overly complicated. A self anti join in an in clause of the same table? You hardly get this any less readable I daresay. Look at jarlh's answer how simple this actually is. (Well, jarlh looks for the gap; if you look for the existing record that creates the gap, that would have to be `min(col)` and `where col - 1 not in` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a Gaps and Islands problem. make row number by id, then get sequential record group.

then use aggregate function get `MIN` and `MAX` id from those group.

- `MIN(ID) -1` NON sequential record end
- `MAX(ID) + 1` NON sequential record start.

final use `LEAD` to get the next NON-sequential record start value.

You can try this.

```
with cte as (
    SELECT MIN(ID) -1  startnum,MAX(ID) +1 endnum
    FROM (
       SELECT  id,id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) grp
       FROM T
    ) t1
    group by grp
)

SELECT endnum from_gap,to_gap 
FROM (
    select *,lead(startnum) over(order by startnum) to_gap
    from cte
) t1
where t1.to_gap is not null
```